# Python web serve JSON feeds from my Postgres DB

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql, web2py

I'm a python/postgres developer and have populated quite a few Postgres databases with statistics for my own and companies data analytics projects.

I now would like to have a web layer where I can create some JSON feeds which I will use https://www.geckoboard.com to listen to and provide a webfront end analytics for my company dashboards.

I'm very comfortable with the querying and creating dictionaries from my DBs so should I use a web framework like web2py/Django to serve the JSON or is this overkill? I also might want to merge data from multiple databases an export into one JSON feed on the fly after the feed URL is called.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for a simple helloworld app/server example which I should follow. I've checked out: http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer but I kinda see this as overkill but maybe I'm wrong!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think Geckoboard "listens" to feeds -- rather, you push data to it by making calls to its API (via a Node.js module they provide). There is no reason you would need to provide a JSON feed over HTTP in order to populate Geckoboard (i.e., it does not make calls to *your* API -- *you* make calls to *its* API). On the other hand, if you're prepared to set up your own server, maybe you should just host your own dashboard front-end (i.e., no need for Geckoboard). I think we need to know more about your preferences and requirements before making recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I love Django and wouldn't hesitate to use it for what you are doing.  In fact, I have many such django instances doing pretty much what you are.  Some might consider it overkill, Django is a bit "heavy" between the request/response, but unless you really start pounding your web app, you won't notice.

Another alternative that I've seen people use is Flask.  It's a bit more "light weight"